# Вызов сценария при загрузке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Со всем недавно начал изучать JS. Вот решил попробывать с jquery. Начал с разбора POPUP окна.

Задача его очень проста
http://prntscr.com/btke70

Вывести окно по клику.

И так код JS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


 $('body').append('<div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-1"><div class="close">X</div><div class="top">text</h2></div><div class="bottom">text</div></div>');
 $('body').append('<div id="blackout"></div>');
 
 var boxWidth = 800;
 
 function centerBox() {
  
  /* Preliminary information */
  var winWidth = $(window).width();
  var winHeight = $(document).height();
  var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
  /* auto scroll bug */
  
  /* Calculate positions */
  
  var disWidth = (winWidth - boxWidth) / 2
  var disHeight = scrollPos + 150;
  
  /* Move stuff about */
  $('.popup-box').css({'width' : boxWidth+'px', 'left' : disWidth+'px', 'top' : disHeight+'px'});
  $('#blackout').css({'width' : winWidth+'px', 'height' : winHeight+'px'});
 
  return false;
 }
 
 
 $(window).resize(centerBox);
 $(window).scroll(centerBox);
 centerBox(); 

 $('[class*=popup-link]').click(function(e) {
 
  /* Prevent default actions */
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  /* Get the id (the number appended to the end of the classes) */
  var name = $(this).attr('class');
  var id = name[name.length - 1];
  var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
  
  /* Show the correct popup box, show the blackout and disable scrolling */
  $('#popup-box-'+id).show();
  $('#blackout').show();
  $('html,body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  
  /* Fixes a bug in Firefox */
  $('html').scrollTop(scrollPos);
 });
 $('[class*=popup-box]').click(function(e) { 
  /* Stop the link working normally on click if it's linked to a popup */
  e.stopPropagation(); 
 });
 $('html').click(function() { 
  var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
  /* Hide the popup and blackout when clicking outside the popup */
  $('[id^=popup-box-]').hide(); 
  $('#blackout').hide(); 
  $("html,body").css("overflow","auto");
  $('html').scrollTop(scrollPos);
 });
 $('.close').click(function() { 
  var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
  /* Similarly, hide the popup and blackout when the user clicks close */
  $('[id^=popup-box-]').hide(); 
  $('#blackout').hide(); 
  $("html,body").css("overflow","auto");
  $('html').scrollTop(scrollPos);
 });
});
```

```css
.popup-box {
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: #fff;
 display: none;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 z-index: 9999999;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.popup-box .close {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #434343;
 padding: 20px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.popup-box .close:hover {
 color: #000;
}

.popup-box h2 {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 18px;
}
.popup-box .top {
 padding: 20px;
}

.popup-box .bottom {
 background: #eee;
 border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 padding: 20px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

#blackout {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 9999;
 left: 0;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<a class="popup-link-1" href="">Нажми на меня, для вывода popup окна!</a>

</body>
</html>
```

У меня два вопроса.

Как сделать вывод окна не по клику, а по сценарию загрузки страницы? Тоесть попал на страницу = открылось окно.

Второй.
Как подвязать куки к этому окну? Тоесть я его увидел, нажал на "х", и дальше мне скрипт его не выводит, например на протяжении недели.

Всем спасибо!

Comment: Здравствуйте, незачто

Comment: Кликнуть на элемент по загрузке страницы скриптом `element.click();` или самовызывающая функция `(function() { ... })();`

Comment: А куда мне самовызывающеюся функцию пихнуть? Вы привели пример для JavaS, тут JQuery. Хоть и одно и тоже, но все же.У меня тут идет такое $(document).ready(function() {, я понимаю что нужно тут внести правку, но как именно...

Comment: Туда, где нужно чтобы её содержимое вызывалась